# code editor Brackets: getting "ERROR: 'document' is not defined. [no-udef]

Tags: brackets

I've installed Brackets and now Im getting an error [no-undef]. I've browsed the net for a solution, but I havn't been able to resolve this problem. I know that this is linked to ESlint, and i've been trying to edit the .eslintrc.json file with suggestions that i've stumbled accros in similiar posts. Anyone had this issue and can share his knowledge?